# React native asyncstorage get token problem

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I tried to get token in register function. But when i called getToken, i get the token but not in the register function. What is the problem? I can't get the token in register() while i called the getToken.

```
getToken = async () =>{
        let token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')
        console.log(token)
        return token
    }

    register=()=>{
        var token = this.getToken()
        console.log(token)
        fetch('http://192.168.0.1:8887/api/auth/activities/register',{
            method: 'POST',
            headers:{
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token,
            },

        })
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question but you should add await before calling this.getToken():
`var token = await this.getToken()`

Comment: @MahdiN i means in the console log in getToken i can get wait i want, but when i return it to the register(). It show me ntg.

Comment: @MahdiN OK i get what u means. I just directly use the ```await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')``` in register(). Its work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call getItem() from another function you can edit your code like this:

```
getToken = async () => AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token');

register = async () => {
    var token = await this.getToken();
    console.log(token); // Now it should log your token
    fetch('http://192.168.0.125:8887/api/auth/activities/register',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token,
        },

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
register = async () =>{
        var token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('id_token')
        console.log(token)
```

I just simply use this and the problem solved.